# pg_ctl promote not suspending replication quickly

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I have a two-node PostgreSQL cluster. One is the primary (192.168.50.3) and one the secondary (192.168.50.4). My `recovery.conf` looks like below on 192.168.50.4.

```
standby_mode          = 'on'
primary_conninfo      = 'host=192.168.50.3 port=5432 user=myuser password=<password_here> sslmode=require sslcompression=0'
trigger_file = '/tmp/make_master'
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
```

Now I run `pg_ctl promote` on the secondary (192.168.50.4) and as soon as the command succeeds, I delete some data from the master (192.168.50.3), and the deleted data also getting deleted from the secondary (192.168.50.4).

Does `pg_ctl promote` take time to actually suspend the replication?
How I can make sure that replication is properly suspended?

logs from `/var/log/messages` on 192.168.50.4:

```
May 10 06:17:45 cluster-node6 sudo: myuser : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/myuser ; USER=postgres ; COMMAND=/usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_ctl promote --pgdata=/var/lib/pgsql/11/data
May 10 06:17:45 cluster-node6 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user postgres by csadmin(uid=0)
May 10 06:17:45 cluster-node6 postmaster: 2019-05-10 06:17:45 UTC LOG:  received promote request
May 10 06:17:45 cluster-node6 postmaster: 2019-05-10 06:17:45 UTC LOG:  received promote request
May 10 06:17:45 cluster-node6 postmaster: 2019-05-10 06:17:45 UTC FATAL:  terminating walreceiver process due to administrator command
May 10 06:17:45 cluster-node6 postmaster: 2019-05-10 06:17:45 UTC FATAL:  terminating walreceiver process due to administrator command
May 10 06:17:45 cluster-node6 postmaster: 2019-05-10 06:17:45 UTC LOG:  redo done at 0/891BFB8
May 10 06:17:45 cluster-node6 postmaster: 2019-05-10 06:17:45 UTC LOG:  redo done at 0/891BFB8
May 10 06:17:45 cluster-node6 postmaster: 2019-05-10 06:17:45 UTC LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2019-05-10 06:17:45.550363+00
May 10 06:17:45 cluster-node6 postmaster: 2019-05-10 06:17:45 UTC LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2019-05-10 06:17:45.550363+00
May 10 06:17:45 cluster-node6 postmaster: 2019-05-10 06:17:45 UTC LOG:  selected new timeline ID: 2
May 10 06:17:45 cluster-node6 postmaster: 2019-05-10 06:17:45 UTC LOG:  selected new timeline ID: 2
May 10 06:17:45 cluster-node6 postmaster: 2019-05-10 06:17:45 UTC LOG:  archive recovery complete
May 10 06:17:45 cluster-node6 postmaster: 2019-05-10 06:17:45 UTC LOG:  archive recovery complete
May 10 06:17:45 cluster-node6 postmaster: 2019-05-10 06:17:45 UTC LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
May 10 06:17:45 cluster-node6 postmaster: 2019-05-10 06:17:45 UTC LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
May 10 06:17:45 cluster-node6 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user postgres
```

Comment: What can you see in the standby's log file?

Comment: Unfortunately, logs are redirected to console. I don't have them

Comment: You should fix that. Does promotion not work at all, or do you only experience a delay (which would be natural).

Comment: `pg_ctl promote` gets succeed (return 0) and then only i delete the data from primary and observing data is getting deleted from secondary as well.

Comment: added logs from /var/log/messages

Comment: Well, the log says that the standby promoted at 2019-05-10 06:17:45 UTC. After that time it will not replicate changes from the primary. At what exact time did you observe that data was replicated? Perhaps you connected to a different replica or something like that.

Comment: Do you know whether promote is synchronous or async ? Logically it MUST be sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promotion is asynchronous. It sends a signal to the postmaster, who then performs the sequence you see in the log.

So it is normal that replication continues for a little while after `pg_ctl promote` has sent the signal successfully.

If you need to make sure that promotion is completed, keep calling the function `pg_is_in_recovery()` until it returns `FALSE`.

From PostgreSQL v12 on, you can call my function `pg_promote()` to promote a standby, which will by default wait until promotion is complete.

Comment: But what is that exact time ? See i have script written which promote and immediately delete some data from master. Will sleep of sometime will help ?

Comment: Can i make it synchronous ? How to do it ?

Comment: See my extended answer.

Comment: Hi Laurenz,
Need one help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193223/postgresql-9-6-error-invalid-resource-manager-id
Is above link valid for PostgreSQL 11 ? We are using `stream` method and saw the mentioned problem on link.

Comment: Never heard of that problem. Sounds like `pg_basebackup` didn't finish. Maybe open another question for that.

Comment: Opened it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56087393/pg-basebackup-and-pg-rewind-failing-to-start-postgresql-service-in-cluster-after