# pg_basebackup and pg_rewind failing to start PostgreSQL service in cluster after failover

Tags: postgresql

I have three node PostgreSQL cluster in which one is master node (192.168.50.3) and two slave nodes (192.168.50.4 and 192.168.50.5). Running following command on slave nodes to take the base backup.

```
pg_basebackup -h 192.168.50.3 -D <postgres_data_dir> -U <replication_user_name> --wal-method=stream -d 'sslmode=require sslcompression=0'
```

Once above command returns 0 (success), creating the `recovery.conf` file.
 `recovery.conf` looks like below on slave nodes:

```
standby_mode          = 'on'
primary_conninfo      = 'host=192.168.50.3 port=5432 user=myuser password=<password_here> sslmode=require sslcompression=0'
trigger_file = '/tmp/make_master'
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
```

Now when i start the PostgreSQL service on slave nodes, the replication works fine.
Now for failover, shutting down the primary (192.168.50.3) then i am promoting slave (192.168.50.4) and then trying to point the slave (192.168.50.5) to new master (192.168.50.4). For that doing following:

1. stop PostgreSQL on 192.168.50.5
2. Use `pg_rewind`

```
/usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_rewind -D <data_dir_path> --source-server="port=5432 user=<username> host=192.168.50.4"
```

3. Create the recovery.conf to point to new master as follows:

```
standby_mode          = 'on'
primary_conninfo      = 'host=192.168.50.4 port=5432 user=myuser password=<password_here> sslmode=require sslcompression=0'
trigger_file = '/tmp/make_master'
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
```

4. Start the PostgreSQL service.
   After starting PostgreSQL service, getting below:

```
LOG: invalid resource manager ID <some_id_here>
```

OR
PostgreSQL logs keeps saying

```
 postgres: startup   recovering 000000060000000000
```

Not able to figure out what is wrong here.

1. Do i need to make sure slave (192.168.50.5) replication is NOT in progress before joining the new master (192.168.50.4).
2. Should i first promote the slave (192.168.50.5) and then join cluster with new master (192.168.50.4) with taking fresh backup from 192.168.50.4 always instead of syncing using `pg_rewind`
3. Any other standard practice that need to follow?

Logs from slave (192.168.50.5). 
Did following:
 1. Promote the 192.168.50.5 and then join the cluster with 192.168.50.4 using `pg_rewind`

```
May 20 09:24:24 myhost postgres[23471]: [11-1] 2019-05-20 09:24:24 UTC LOG:  received promote request
May 20 09:24:24 myhost postgres[23471]: [12-1] 2019-05-20 09:24:24 UTC LOG:  redo done at 0/8065B60
May 20 09:24:24 myhost postgres[23471]: [13-1] 2019-05-20 09:24:24 UTC LOG:  selected new timeline ID: 2
May 20 09:24:25 myhost postgres[23471]: [14-1] 2019-05-20 09:24:25 UTC LOG:  archive recovery complete
May 20 09:24:25 myhost postgres[23463]: [7-1] 2019-05-20 09:24:25 UTC LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
May 20 09:25:35 myhost postgres[23463]: [8-1] 2019-05-20 09:25:35 UTC LOG:  received fast shutdown request
May 20 09:25:35 myhost postgres[23463]: [9-1] 2019-05-20 09:25:35 UTC LOG:  aborting any active transactions
May 20 09:25:35 myhost postgres[23650]: [8-1] 2019-05-20 09:25:35 UTC FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator com
mand
May 20 09:25:35 myhost postgres[23463]: [10-1] 2019-05-20 09:25:35 UTC LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher"
(PID 23635) exited with exit code 1
May 20 09:25:35 myhost postgres[23472]: [6-1] 2019-05-20 09:25:35 UTC LOG:  shutting down
May 20 09:25:35 myhost postgres[23463]: [11-1] 2019-05-20 09:25:35 UTC LOG:  database system is shut down
May 20 09:25:51 myhost postgres[25121]: [1-1] 2019-05-20 09:25:51 UTC LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
May 20 09:25:51 myhost postgres[25121]: [2-1] 2019-05-20 09:25:51 UTC LOG:  could not create IPv6 socket for address "::": Ad
dress family not supported by protocol
May 20 09:25:51 myhost postgres[25121]: [3-1] 2019-05-20 09:25:51 UTC LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.
PGSQL.5432"
May 20 09:25:51 myhost postgres[25121]: [4-1] 2019-05-20 09:25:51 UTC LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
May 20 09:25:51 myhost postgres[25121]: [5-1] 2019-05-20 09:25:51 UTC LOG:  ending log output to stderr
May 20 09:25:51 myhost postgres[25121]: [5-2] 2019-05-20 09:25:51 UTC HINT:  Future log output will go to log destination "sy
slog".
May 20 09:25:51 myhost postgres[25129]: [6-1] 2019-05-20 09:25:51 UTC LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-05-20 09:25
:35 UTC
May 20 09:25:51 myhost postgres[25121]: [6-1] 2019-05-20 09:25:51 UTC LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
May 20 09:25:58 myhost postgres[25373]: [7-1] 2019-05-20 09:25:58 UTC LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection re
set by peer
May 20 09:26:07 myhost postgres[25121]: [7-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:07 UTC LOG:  received fast shutdown request
May 20 09:26:07 myhost postgres[25121]: [8-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:07 UTC LOG:  aborting any active transactions
May 20 09:26:07 myhost postgres[25496]: [7-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:07 UTC FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator com
mand
May 20 09:26:07 myhost postgres[25303]: [7-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:07 UTC FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator com
mand
May 20 09:26:07 myhost postgres[25478]: [7-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:07 UTC FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator com
mand
May 20 09:26:07 myhost postgres[25121]: [9-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:07 UTC LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher"
(PID 25138) exited with exit code 1
May 20 09:26:07 myhost postgres[25133]: [6-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:07 UTC LOG:  shutting down
May 20 09:26:07 myhost postgres[25121]: [10-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:07 UTC LOG:  database system is shut down
May 20 09:26:17 myhost postgres[25661]: [1-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:17 UTC LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
May 20 09:26:17 myhost postgres[25661]: [2-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:17 UTC LOG:  could not create IPv6 socket for address "::": Ad
dress family not supported by protocol
May 20 09:26:17 myhost postgres[25661]: [3-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:17 UTC LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.
PGSQL.5432"
May 20 09:26:17 myhost postgres[25661]: [4-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:17 UTC LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
May 20 09:26:17 myhost postgres[25661]: [5-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:17 UTC LOG:  ending log output to stderr
May 20 09:26:17 myhost postgres[25661]: [5-2] 2019-05-20 09:26:17 UTC HINT:  Future log output will go to log destination "sy
slog".
May 20 09:26:17 myhost postgres[25670]: [6-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:17 UTC LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-05-20 09:26
:07 UTC
May 20 09:26:17 myhost postgres[25670]: [7-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:17 UTC LOG:  entering standby mode
May 20 09:26:17 myhost postgres[25670]: [8-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:17 UTC LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/806CF98
May 20 09:26:17 myhost postgres[25670]: [9-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:17 UTC LOG:  invalid record length at 0/806CF98: wanted 24, go
t 0
May 20 09:26:17 myhost postgres[25661]: [6-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:17 UTC LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only conn
ections
May 20 09:26:17 myhost postgres[25674]: [7-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:17 UTC LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 0/8000000 o
n timeline 2
May 20 09:26:17 myhost postgres[25670]: [10-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:17 UTC LOG:  invalid resource manager ID 45 at 0/806CF98
May 20 09:26:17 myhost postgres[25674]: [8-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:17 UTC FATAL:  terminating walreceiver process due to administ
rator command
May 20 09:26:17 myhost postgres[25670]: [11-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:17 UTC LOG:  invalid resource manager ID 45 at 0/806CF98
May 20 09:26:17 myhost postgres[25670]: [12-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:17 UTC LOG:  invalid resource manager ID 45 at 0/806CF98
May 20 09:26:22 myhost postgres[25670]: [13-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:22 UTC LOG:  invalid resource manager ID 45 at 0/806CF98
May 20 09:26:27 myhost postgres[25670]: [14-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:27 UTC LOG:  invalid resource manager ID 45 at 0/806CF98
May 20 09:26:32 myhost postgres[25670]: [15-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:32 UTC LOG:  invalid resource manager ID 45 at 0/806CF98
May 20 09:26:37 myhost postgres[25670]: [16-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:37 UTC LOG:  invalid resource manager ID 45 at 0/806CF98
May 20 09:26:42 myhost postgres[25670]: [17-1] 2019-05-20 09:26:42 UTC LOG:  invalid resource manager ID 45 at 0/806CF98
```

`pg_rewind` failure on 50.5 while joining new primary 50.4

```
[root@myhost user]# su - postgres  -c "/usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_rewind -D /var/lib/pgsql/11/data --source-server=\"port=5432 user=myuser host=192.168.50.4 dbname='db_name'\" --dry-run --debug"
fetched file "global/pg_control", length 8192
fetched file "pg_wal/00000002.history", length 41
Source timeline history:
Target timeline history:
1: 0/0 - 0/0
servers diverged at WAL location 0/8030178 on timeline 1

could not find previous WAL record at 0/8030178: invalid record length at 0/8030178: wanted 24, got 0
Failure, exiting
```

Comment: Can you show more of the log file from 192.168.50.5?

Comment: This is not happening frequently. Can you please suggest on :

Do i need to make sure slave (192.168.50.5) replication is NOT in progress before joining the new master (192.168.50.4).


Should i first promote the slave (192.168.50.5) and then join cluster with new master (192.168.50.4) with taking fresh backup from 192.168.50.4 always instead of syncing using pg_rewind


Any other standard practice that need to follow?

Comment: In case of failover, how should other cluster node point to new primary. From what i read, 

1. Stop PostgreSQL.

2. sync the cluster with new primary using `pg_rewind`

3. Update the IP address in `recovery.conf` to new primary IP

4. Start the PostgreSQL.

Comment: You don't need to wait for promotion to finish before redirecting the second standby (cascading replication). To understand what went wrong, it would be helpful to see the log file.

Comment: Ok. Can you please tell me whether this is correct understanding :
In case of failover, how should other cluster node point to new primary. From what i read, 1. Stop PostgreSQL. 2. sync the cluster with new primary using pg_rewind 3. Update the IP address in recovery.conf to new primary IP 4. Start the PostgreSQL.

I will try to reproduce the issue and collect the logs.

Comment: Your procedure looks correct.

Comment: ok thanks for the confirmation. Let me try to reproduce.

Comment: added the log in question

Comment: Can i reset the wal using `/usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_resetwal -f /var/lib/pgsql/11/data/` of slave node first and then join the cluster with new primary?

Comment: What i observed is the wal file having last checkoint is corrupted, hence i am facing the issue. If i reset the wal using `pg_resetwal` and then use the `pg_rewind`, will that work ?

Comment: Or how i can reset the postgresql to previous checkout ?

Comment: `pg_resetval` leads to a corrupted database and is therefore a last ditch measure. Don't do it, as your primary is not corrupted. If you have a corrupted WAL file, you have to rebuild the standby from scratch. How did it happen?

Comment: Scenario is like this: Original master (192.168.50.3) is completely down. Now slaves 50.4 and 50.5 were pointing to 50.3 initially. Now i am promoting the 50.4 as new primary and the new primary is working perfectly fine. But when i try to join the slave 50.5 to new primary 50.4, i am getting above error complaining about the "invalid resource manager ID 45 " in consistent recovery check wal.

Comment: What i want to achieve is, in case of failover, the other hot stand by nodes should be able to use `pg_rewind` to sync with new primary and avoid the full basebackup of new primary.

Comment: In my scenario, i have multiple hot standby servers.

Comment: WAL doesn't just become corrupted. Figure out what happened. Recover from the problem by rebuilding the standby. I cannot tell you what went wrong with your installation.

Comment: Exactly same issue as of this, but no solution : https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/HK2PR0301MB104359382242EFEEB934B3DEC0D50%40HK2PR0301MB1043.apcprd03.prod.outlook.com

Comment: Same issue : https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CADmi%3D6O_RApqN%3D4QWA72gAqt96p0s1%2B3g%2B%3DpN1xgEhVVPzt6qg%40mail.gmail.com

Comment: You are not using an ancient version of PostgreSQL, are you?

Comment: Using latest version, PostgreSQL 11, but still having same issue.

Comment: The issue comes only if master (192.168.50.3 ) is shutdown during takeover of (192.168.50.4).

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe,
Looks like it was the issue with `pg_rewind`. I can see in PostgreSQL 13, there is fix around this:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/release-13.html#id-1.11.6.9.5

Have pg_rewind automatically run crash recovery before rewinding (Paul Guo, Jimmy Yih, Ashwin Agrawal)

This can be disabled by using --no-ensure-shutdown.
Can you please confirm this fix is same what current problem is?

Comment: Then you didn't tell us the truth. You didn't tell us that `pg_rewind` was failing.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe My question heading itself mention about the `pg_rewind`?

Comment: You said "failing to start", but you didn't show us the messages from `pg_rewind`. Anyway, you seem to have solved your problem. Perhaps write an answer to your own question so that others can benefit.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Can you please confirm if PostgreSQL 13 resolved this?

Comment: The documentation doesn't lie, and `pg_rewind` will perform crash recovery.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe My problem is not yet solved. I just checked the PostgreSQL 13 release notes. It shows something around this. Hence i thought asking you before i try with PostgreSQL 13.